# How to install thrift into a virtualenv?

Tags: python, thrift

I want to install Apache Thrift into a python virtualenv.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simply as that:

```
$ virtualenv foo
$ cd foo
$ . bin/activate
(foo)$ pip install thrift
```